# AngularJS Coding Artifice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a code snippet.

```
$scope.$watch('year', reloadData);
$scope.$watch('month', reloadData);

$scope.year = 2017;
$scope.month = 1;

var reloadData = function() {
   /* Reload Data  */ 
}

var init = function() {
    $scope.year = 2015;
    $scope.month = 3;  
}

init();
```

Do you think how many times does the function "reloadData" is called after init? Is there any solution to call reloadData once when year and month are changed at the same time? Like this:

```
<input ng-model="year" name="year" id="year">
<input ng-model="month" name="month" id="month">
```

when change year => reloadData is called.

when change month => reloadData is called.

when change month and year => reloadData is called only once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, forexample you can use multiple watch

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['year', 'month'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
//newValues[0]  is your new year
//newValues[1]  is your new month

if((newValues[0] != oldValues[0]) && (newValues[1] != oldValues[1]))
{//reload()}
}
```